# extract `.sh` scripts from a string and reformat them

Tags: text-processing, sudo

I have a string like :

```
%group1 ALL=(ALL) /ora/crs/oracle/product/crs/bin/gsdctl *,/ora/crs/oracle/product/crs/bin/vipca,/ora/app/oracle/ora/Root.sh,/ora/crs/oracle/product/crs/root.sh,/ora/crs/oracle/product/crs/bin/srvctl *,/ora/app/oracle/product/root.sh
```

Output should be : (print only .sh scripts)

```
/ora/app/oracle/ora/Root.sh    
/ora/crs/oracle/product/crs/root.sh
/ora/app/oracle/product/root.sh
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not actually parsing /etc/sudoers with bash, are you? Are you rather more interested in extracting certain lines from /etc/sudoers in some way, formatting particularly?

Answer (score 1):

In this example this also works as comma is only used to separate absolute paths:

```
grep -o '/[^,]*\.sh' file
```

Comment: Hole in one. Nice golfing. Didn't need the look behind ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your line is the only line in file `file`, you can use `sed`

```
cat file | sed 's/,/\n/g' | sed -n '/\.sh$/ p'
```

The first `sed` command replaces all commas by a line break, and the second prints all lines ending on `.sh`. So we could also do it without `sed`:

```
cat file | tr ',' '\n' | grep '\.sh$'
```

Comment: Note that the input looks a lot like a sudoers file, which likely has comments and other lines in it.

Comment: Care to elaborate the second `sed` expression for me? My guess is it checks for the existence of .sh at the end of each line and `p`rints only those?

Comment: If the input is, indeed, a sudoers file, note that (oddly-named, granted) files with commas in them can be quoted; e.g. `.../ora/app/oracle/product/root.sh,/other/comma\,command.sh,...`

Comment: @Panki: The second `sed` command searches for lines containing `.sh` followed by an end-of-line `$`, i.e. lines ending on `.sh`. The `p` means **print**, and `-n` suppresses the usual output of every line.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative without `sed`, though still vulnerable to commas in path/filenames

```
grep -Po "(?<=[, ])[^,]*\.sh(?=,|$)" test
```